ogre-next package in Ubuntu
I am compiling my ogre-next application in cpp from the .so libraries provided by the
ogre-next package in Ubuntu.
The main libs .so are right in the current release, ex the OgreNextMain.so,
but in the package are missing the RenderSystem libraries, ex the RenderSystem_GLES3.
Could be these libraries from the RenderSystem folder be added to the package?
